# Global on enter function for all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, enter, onkeyup

i have written a code :

```
$('*').on('keyup',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
          $(this).trigger('click');
    } 
});
```

the above code works fine until jquery dialog. Apparently whenever i hit an enter key in the dialog. it sort of like bubbles up the event.

i have 2 dialogs. 1st is the confirm dialog and 2nd is the message dialog. when i hit yes it will pop up the message dialog and when i hit ok on the message dialog the confirm dialog will open again.

i tried like this :

```
 $('*').not('.ui-button').on('keyup',function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
              $(this).trigger('click');
        } 
    });
```

this is for the exclusion of the ui-buttons for the enter events. it did not work. Any help would be appreciated. thanks

**EDIT** :

note that i call the dialogs to open using a link. i wonder if that link is focused when i hit enter so it calls the dialog again when i hit enter on the message dialog.

Comment: make a fiddle, it will be easier to solve using fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Why not cancel its event by using `off`?

```
$('*').on('keyup',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
          $(this).trigger('click');
    } 
}).find(".ui-buttons").off('keyup'); // this unbinds the event so it won't trigger
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the ui buttons are not created when the handlers are registered.

One approach you can do is to register a single handler to the document object, then see whether the actual target is a `ui-button` like

```
$(document).on('keyup', function (e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if ($target.closest('.ui-button').length) {
        return;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $target.trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code, this code exclude `.ui-button` element and inner elements of `.ui-button` class

```
$('body').on('keyup',function(e){
     if(!$(e.target).closest('.ui-button').length && e.keyCode == 13){
           $(e.target).trigger('click');
      } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I admit I'm not a big fan of global bindings, especially because of these problems. I find it better to specify the types and/or location of the elements I want to bind the event to.

One of the reasons is this event bubbling that sadly does not behave the same way in all browsers.

My suggestion is to bind the event only to the desired elements and add `e.stopPropagation()` to the called function(s).

I know this is not the answer you were looking for but I believe you should consider this method for being more specific (and more reliable).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by blurring the link that i clicked to open the dialog.

something like :

```
$('.links').find('a').on('click',function(){
     $(this).blur();
});
```